# How to add child element after Root element

Tags: c#, xml, appendchild, document-root

I've the following function, that I can pass my C# object to which can then convert it to Xml.

```
public static XmlDocument SerializeObjectToXML(object obj)
{
  XmlSerializer serializer = 
      new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
     XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
     serializer.Serialize(ms, obj);
     ms.Position = 0;
     xmlDoc.Load(ms);
  }
}
```

However, I need to add a Child Element  after the Root.  For example at the moment I have

```
<MyObjectResponse>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>Mr Smith</Name>
    <Numbers>
      <Number>100</Number>
      <Number>200</Number>
    </Numbers>
</MyObjectResponse>
```

But want the output to

```
<MyObjectResponse>
  <Response>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>Mr Smith</Name>
    <Numbers>
      <Number>100</Number>
      <Number>200</Number>
    </Numbers>
  </Response>
</MyObjectResponse>
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Please see my edit. Just replace the previous `foreach` loop with the current `while` loop. It should work as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
serializer.Serialize(ms, obj);
ms.Position = 0;
xmlDoc.Load(ms);

XmlElement newElem = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Response");

//wrong: works for only 1 child element
//kept for edit/reference
//foreach (XmlNode item in xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
//{
//    newElem.AppendChild(item);
//}

while (xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Count != 0)
{
    newElem.AppendChild(xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[0]);
}

xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(newElem);
```

**EDIT** replaced the `foreach` loop with a correct and general implementation using a `while` loop.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to keep all the existing Child elements

Comment: @Tommo1977, sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. Where do you want to keep the existing child elements?